# Find crossing edges in a graph from adjacency matrix

Tags: planar-graphs, adjacency-matrix

Is there any way to find the crossing edges from the adjacency matrix of a given undirected graph $G=(V,E)$? For example in the following graph ( actually a tree in this specific example) $e_{3, 13}$ and $e_{1, 14}$ are crossing, how can I extract this information from the adjacency matrix of the graph? Coordinates of all vertices are given and fix.

[image]

Comment: Short answer: no. The adjacency matrix encodes only the connectedness, nothing about the positions of vertices. The rest of your question makes no sense to me. You will have to [edit] it to get help here.  (The graph in your example is actually a tree.)

Comment: Thanks Dr. Bolker.

Comment: Perhaps a more interesting problem: Given the adjacency matrix of a graph, find the minimum possible number of crossing edges. An easier version: Given the adjacency matrix of graph, determine if it is planar. The easier version can be extended to toroidal, etc. The minimum number of crossing edges is known as the crossing number